# Is it permissible to earn money on Shabbos if paid at another time?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, money, employment

For example if a shul had a children's program, a chazan who was only there on Shabbos, or a catering company who set up kiddush for the shul...

The fact that all these examples only take place during Shabbos, is it a problem that they be paid at another time since the earning of that money took place on Shabbos?

Answer (score 2):

As DanF stated in his comment, the common practice is to pay them for a service that included some non-Shabbos time, so we're not strictly paying for time on Shabbos. For instance:

*Children's program*: prepare posters or games before Shabbos, and use them on Shabbos.

*Chazzan*: prepare music before Shabbos and perform on Shabbos.

*Caterer*: often some of their setup will be done before Shabbos.

*Babysitter*: if you need one Friday night, it's best to ask him/her to arrive a few minutes before Shabbos, so that way you're paying for non-Shabbos time too. Similarly if you need one for late Saturday afternoon, have them stay until Havdalah, so they babysat on non-Shabbos as well.

Comment: Re caterer - Perhaps, even the food cooking itself may suffice, as you are paying them for that, as well. In other words, I don't think it requires any physical set-up in the place, itself. As a matter of fact, in many places, tables & chairs are set up on Shabbat, itself, and food is delivered (carried within an eruv, of course) on Shabbat.

Comment: As always, citing sources for your claims would improve your answer.

Comment: Like this one, for example: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/ערוך_השולחן_אורח_חיים_שו#סימן_שו_סעיף_ט

Comment: reminder to edit in sources